# How to validate only when content is filled in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a class with several attributes.
One is month and another is year.
It is not mandatory to fill those fields.
Leaving both blank should be accepted.
But in case just one of them is filled, both of them should be validated (according to @Min and @Max below) so that it is a valid month/year date.
How do I implement that condition?
The code below makes it mandatory to fill both. Doesn't accept the first condition (both empty).

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Other attributes here
    
    @Min(value=1, message="Invalid month")
    @Max(value=12, message="Invalid month")
    private int month;
    
    @Min(value=1900, message="Invalid year")
    @Max(value=2100, message="Invalid year")
    private int year;
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSR-303` addresses this. You can create a custom validator annotation `@ValidMonthAndYear` on `Person.java`.

**ValidMonthAndYear.java**

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(
    validatedBy = {MonthAndYearValidator.class}
)
public @interface ValidMonthAndYear {
    String message() default "Missing Month or Year";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

**MonthAndYearValidator.java**

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class MonthAndYearValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidMonthAndYear, Person> {


    public boolean isValid(Person person, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        //Logic here to validate Person attributes
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tushar. This seems kind of complicated to me though. Easier to forget about annotations in this case and just do a simple check to see if the fields were filled and, in that case, pass the values to a simple function to check if the values are within the range. Sometimes doing it yourself is easier than trying to go for framework solutions.

Comment: Agreed. It is only useful if you are reusing the validation across multiple places.